# bind_param Error 500

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I have the following script called via javascript POST

```
$target = $_POST['id'];
$sid = $_POST['sid'];

$sql = 'DELETE FROM `subusers` WHERE `subusers.uid`=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo $target;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $target);
$stmt->execute();
```

Whenever executed, for some reason it crashes with `POST http://xx.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`. When bind_param is deleted, it works fine. The PHP also communicates with the script that called it, I tried sending the value of $target back to the script and alerting it and it shows a good value. I also tried `$target=1` just for the sake of declaring it as an integer but it changed nothing. The whole mess in the query is just me trying to fix it in case there was a keyword somewhere.

Error code:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/delpar.php on line 12, referer:
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/delpar.php on line 17, referer:

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, enable PHP's error display. At the top of your script (or enable in php.ini on a dev machine) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Meanwhile, the 500 error should be detailed in your web server's error log.

Comment: Oh, it's here: `\`subusers.uid\`` should be quoted as `\`subusers\`.\`uid\`` wherein each part of the identifier is surrounded in its own pair of backticks.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski still returns error 500. Where is the log located on a standard linux httpd installation?

Comment: On a Debian-like system, probably `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, on a Red Hat like system `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: @aron9forever Well, the first error would appear to indicate your mysqli connection `$conn` has died somewhere. Please post the code preceding this, wherever you may have connected and used `$conn`. It was somehow closed before you attempted this statement, or it was never connected successfully to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you were right, the connection was closed above in an included script. I don't know how I didn't notice this. I did not know about the error log however. Thank you. Please post as an answer

Comment: @aron9forever Ok, answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are are few issues here causing your `prepare()/bind_param()/execute()` to fail. The first thing spotted visually is incorrect quoting on the `table.column` included in your `DELETE` statement's `WHERE` clause. MySQL's identifier quoting requires that if quoted, each segment of the identifier be wrapped in its own pair of backticks.

```
// Correct quoting
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `subusers` WHERE `subusers`.`uid`=?';
//-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Always when developing and testing code, it helps to enable PHP's [`display_errors` ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), which would print errors and warnings to the screen rather than requiring you to dig into error logs (also recommended `error_reporting = E_ALL`). But in any case, most default setups log PHP errors to the web server's error log, such as `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Based on the first error message:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/delpar.php on line 12

It is apparent that your MySQLi connection object in `$conn` was either closed or never correctly connected to begin with. Look to earlier code to verify that `$conn->close()` has not already been called.

Comment: Oh, and here I thought I didn't have any votes left ;-) way to go.